# Using SQLAlchemy to connect to OracleDB using python-oracledb instead of cx_Oracle

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

I am trying to create an engine using the python-oracledb library instead of cx_Oracle but it shows cx_Oracle module not found. Is there any way I can make sqlalchemy create an engine using python-oracledb?

I used to create an engine with the following if I was using cx_Oracle:

`conn_str = "oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}"`

I am using the below code to make it use python-oracledb.

```
import oracledb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

oracledb.init_oracle_client()

engine = create_engine(f'oracle://{p_username}:{p_password}@{p_dns}:{p_port}', max_identifier_length=128)

print(engine)
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.oracledb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`oracle://…` is equivalent to `oracle+cx_oracle://…`. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#dialect-oracle-oracledb-connect), if you want to use python-oracledb you need to specify `oracle+oracledb://…`

Comment: Some of the connection variants are discussed in [Using SQLAlchemy 2.0 with python-oracledb for Oracle Database](https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c).

Comment: I am connecting with thick mode but few tables are not fetching data using above python libs. What could be the reason because source tables have data?